# how do I store data into database using javascript

Tags: javascript, database

I am using Google Map API to do address translation(mainly by **geocoder**).

And I'd like to store results into local database for future use since google map has a limit on total query number and frequency.

But how? I have googled and found an ActiveX based solution. Is there platform independent alternatives?

Comment: You don't store data into a database with JavaScript. Instead you use JS to make an AJAX call to a server-side technology like PHP, Ruby, Python, whatever, which communicates with the database. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bajax%5D+database+insert

Comment: @Michael — The question specifically talks about a local database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access a database you are going to need a server side language. JavaScript can talk to PHP through AJAX and PHP can update the database with whatever parameters you give to it via JavaScript.

I would stay away from ActiveX as it can be tricky and you just dont need it.

When you have a database setup, have a look at these websites

- http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqlinsert.php
- http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

Current in-browser database options include [IndexedDB](http://caniuse.com/#search=IndexedDB), [Web SQL](http://caniuse.com/#search=sql), and [Web Storage](http://caniuse.com/#search=storage).

Browser support, however, isn't all that good. Web Storage is your best bet, but it won't work on IE7 and earlier.